# sorting vector<vector<bool>> based on the content of vector<bool>

Tags: c++

I have 2000  `vector<vector<bool>>` and each `vector<bool>` contains 200 elements , I am going to sort this vector of vectors. Supposing that the elements in `vector<bool>` are a one binary number.

original data:

```
vector 1: 1,1,1
vector 2: 1,0,1
vector 3: 0,0,0
vector 4: 1,0,0
```

After sorting:

```
vector 3: 0,0,0
vector 4: 1,0,0
vector 2: 1,0,1
vector 1: 1,1,1
```

It is possible to use `sort` with a special predicate but surprisingly when I call `sort` without a predicate it seems to work anyway.

```
    vector<bool> A = {1, 1, 1};
    vector<bool> B = {1, 0, 1};
    vector<bool> C = {0, 0, 0};
    vector<bool> D = {1, 0, 0};

    vector < vector<bool> > v = {A,B,C,D};

    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
```

and the order is as "after sorting" above.

Why does it work without a special predicate?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Would 0,1,0,0 compare before or after 0,0,1,0? What is your bit endianess?

Comment: First 0,1,0,0 then 0,0,1,0.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it is just a badly worded question.

Comment: I have rephrased the question as to what I think the user is asking

Comment: @CashCow It was certainly a duplicate in its original form.

Comment: @juanchopanza "how to sort a vector of user defined type" is certainly a part of his question and the duplicate answers that. But "how to write a predicate to sort vectors of bool as if they were interpreted as a binary number" is also part of the original question (not with those exact words, but because the answer to the first part is "use std::sort and a predicate") and that is not answered in the duplicate.

Comment: The duplicate shows that you can use std::sort and a predicate. It would be a simple step to figure out why and when the predicate is needed, and what the default behaviour does. I must have forgotten for a moment that we're in the business of spoon-feeding answers to people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough simply to apply standard algorithm `std::sort` declared in header `<algorithm>` because there is defined `operator <` for vectors **provided that all boolean vectors have the same size**.

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> v =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 0, 1 }, {0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 0, 0 }
    };

    std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() );

    for ( const std::vector<bool> &v1 : v )
    {
        for ( bool b : v1 ) std::cout << b << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 0 0 
1 0 0 
1 0 1 
1 1 1
```

Otherwise you could use algorithm `std::accumulate` in a predicate of `std::sort`

Comment: @Quentin It depends on whether all boolean vectors have the same size. As in the original post all vectors have the same size then they will be sorted accordingly.

Comment: After a quick peek at the C++ reference, I take back that comment :)

Comment: Even if they don't have the same size, `<` works just fine because it's the same as `lexicographical_compare`.

Comment: @Anton Savin No, it will not work if to consider boolean vectors as binary representations of unsigned integral numbers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this will not sort the vectors according to the bit-endiannes that OP wants (according to the comments on question).

Comment: @user2079303 in this case it is enough to sort vectors in the descending order.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, no, wouldn't (1 1 1) then be before (0 0 0) which is also wong?

Comment: @user2079303 In this case you will need to use a predicate.

Answer (score 3):

[std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) can take a Compare function. So just define a compare function on `std::vector<bool>` doing what you expect.

Hence you need to define a convention about how to compare two `std::vector<bool>` of *different* lengths.

BTW, it looks like you are re-inventing [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), why don't you use some *existing* library like [gmplib](http://gmplib.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple bubble sorting algorithm on the elements of the outer vector (which are vectors as well), and the condition of swapping would be this:

```
for (int i=0; i<200; i++)
    if (vec1[i] > vec2[i]) vec1.swap(vec2);
    /* vec1 and vec2 are the two vectors you
    compare when bubble sorting the outer vector */
```

Because if you take two binary numbers, iterate through them, and compare each corresponding digit, then the greater of the two numbers is the one that has the highest digit that's a one and the corresponding digit in the other number is a 0. Like this:

0011010110101010000111011011

0010101011101000011101101010

Without converting them to decimal, it's easy to tell that the top one is larger. The first three digits are the same, but the fourth one is greater in the top number. The rest don't matter, this makes the top number bigger. Therefore, it's simple to use this as a swapping condition in bubble sorting.